# Calculating second derivative of $g(\alpha) = f(\textbf{y}(\alpha))$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, partial-derivative

I'm having problems with the second derivative of the function $g(\alpha) = f(\textbf{y}(\alpha))$ (which I will define more precisely below). I tried calculating it myself, could anyone just simply check that my reasoning is correct or not? :) Here goes:

Let $\textbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ and $\textbf{d} = (d_1, d_2, ..., d_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Lets define $\textbf{y}(\alpha) = \textbf{x} + \alpha\textbf{d}$, where $0 \leq \alpha \leq \bar{\alpha}$.

Now lets define the function $g(\alpha) = f(\:\textbf{y}(\alpha)\:)$. Calculate $g''(\alpha)$.

Here is my attempted solution: First I calculate $g'(\alpha)$:

$$g'(\alpha) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}\left( \:f(\:\textbf{y}(\alpha)\: )\: \right) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}(\:f(y_1,y_2, ..., y_n)\:) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}(\: f(x_1 + \alpha d_1, x_2 + \alpha d_2, ..., x_n + \alpha d_n) \:) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1}\cdot\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial \alpha} + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_n}\cdot\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial \alpha} =  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1}\cdot d_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_n}\cdot d_n = \nabla f(\:\textbf{y}(\alpha)\:)\cdot \textbf{d} = h(\textbf{y})$$

Next I calculate $g''(\alpha)$:

$$g''(\alpha) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}(\: h(\textbf{y})\:) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}(\: h(y_1, ..., y_n) \:) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial y_1}\cdot\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial \alpha} + \cdots + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y_n}\cdot\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial \alpha} = \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{\partial h}{\partial y_1}\cdot d_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y_n}\cdot d_n = \nabla h(\: \textbf{y}(\alpha)\:)\cdot \textbf{d}$$

Now:

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial y_i} = \frac{\partial }{\partial y_i} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1}\cdot d_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_n}\cdot d_n \right) = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y_1\partial y_i}\cdot d_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y_n\partial y_i}\cdot d_n$$

So:

$$g''(\alpha) = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y_1^2}\cdot d_1^2 + \cdots + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y_n\partial y_1}\cdot d_nd_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y_1\partial y_n}\cdot d_1d_n + \cdots + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y_n^2}\cdot d_n^2$$

Or:

$$g''(\alpha) = \textbf{d} \;\nabla^2 f(\:\textbf{y}(\alpha)\:) \:\textbf{d}^T$$

As I said before, could someone verify that I got it right? :) Thank you for any help !

Comment: You're right, but you can get that result in lee than three lines ...

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help @MichaelHoppe :) I'm very specific person, I like to see the details. I get easily confused if all the variables and indexes are not well and accurately defined :) I don't like it to look fancy, I want it to look clear ;) I guess I have this phobia for too much abstractness and assumptions, because I never understood my math professors, because they assumed too much. This is of course my personal experience :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Just for the first step: you'll get it immediately via chain rule, as well as the second.  Avoid coordinates!

Comment: +1 Thnx again @MichaelHoppe I will keep your advice in mind :)